# Haskell - lazy function for finding positions of character in text

Tags: haskell

It is correct proposition.

```
positions :: Char -> String -> [Int]
positions c [] = []
positions c xs = [x | (l, x) <- zip xs [1..length xs], l == c]
```

It seems to be elegant and in haskell style. However, I consider is it possible to implement lazy function for this. I mean that for infinity list it also works. 
For example,

```
let li = 'a':list
head $ positions 'a' li
= 1
```

My solution is looping because of length (it is not possible count length for list - looping).

Could you help me ?

Comment: for an infinite list it won't terminate by the given requirement of finding all matches since you can never check all positions.

Comment: @karakfa: `head . positions 'a'` __will__ terminate for any list that contains an `a` at some point, even if the list is infinite and `position` is lazy enough. Still won't terminate for infinite lists that don't contain `a` of course.

Comment: right, didn't check the usage, I was commenting on the positions function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zip xs ys` will stop as soon as one of the two lists is exhausted. It's also lazy:

```
zip (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y) : zip xs ys
zip _      _      = []
```

Therefore, you don't have to get the length first, you can just `zip` with an infinite list:

```
zip xs [1..]
```

If `xs` is finite, the result will be finite, and if `xs` is infinite, the result will also be an infinite list.

By the way, you can simplify your function and make it more general:

```
positions :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
positions c xs = [n | (l, n) <- zip xs [1..], l == c]
```

After all, if `xs` is empty, `zip xs [1..]` will be empty too, and the list comprehension is also the empty list in this case. Also, you want to have a look at `findIndices` in `Data.List`.

Comment: thanks! it works! I couldn;t understand why. Could you explain it ?

Comment: @HaskellFun: Sure, added an explanation.

Comment: FYI, it's probably best to `zip [1..] xs` for efficiency (swapping the argument order), particularly with recent GHC versions.

Comment: @dfeuer: Could you point me to an explanation of your remark? I've never heard of this before!

Comment: @yatima2975: Probably due to [`zip` being right-lazy and special rules](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#zip).

Comment: @yatima2975, Zeta got it right regarding the rules. See especially the comments below the `foldr2/left` rule in the module Zeta linked to. Putting the enumeration first should ensure that the optimization rule fires; putting it second means it will only fire if `xs` is a "good producer".

Comment: Hm. Not sure whether I should change the `zip` above to reflect the right-lazyness.

Comment: @yatima, furthermore, if the result of your function is consumed by a good consumer, GHC may be able to unbox the `Int`s (I believe), but this will surely be impossible if `xs` gets the place of honor.

Comment: thanks you very much ! However, why you name zip lazy ? After all, for infinite list it is looping

Comment: @HaskellFun `take 100 (zip [1..] [1..])`

Comment: @dfeuer and Zeta: Thanks! I usually tune out the optimization rules :-)